# How to Concatenate two result alias columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have below SQL Query

```
Select 
Count(A) AS col1, 
Count(B) AS Col2, 
Count(A) + Count(B) As Col3
FROM myTable
```

Im expecting like

```
Select 
Count(A) AS col1, 
Count(B) AS Col2, 
col1 + Col2 As Col3
FROM myTable
```

Is this possible? Any one can help me regarding this.
Note: this is simple example i have given but in my real query im doing many calculation in col1 and col2

Answer (score 2):

I think a subquery would help here.

```
select col1 + col2 as col3
from (
Select 
Count(A) AS col1, 
Count(B) AS Col2
FROM myTable
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference a column by its alias in the same `SELECT`. You either must repeat the express or define the columns in a CTE/subquery.

Examples:

```sql
--CTE
WITH CTE AS
    SELECT COUNT(A) AS Col1,
           COUNT(B) AS Col2
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       Col1 + Col2 AS Col3
FROM CTE;
--Subquery
SELECT SQ.Col1,
       SQ.Col2,
       SQ.Col1 + SQ.Col2 AS Col3
FROM (SELECT COUNT(A) AS Col1,
             COUNT(B) AS Col2
      FROM dbo.YourTable) SQ;
```

Comment: Thanks Larnu for your quick answer

Comment: You're welcome, @PrabhuP . If it answers the question please do mark the answer as the solution, so that future users know the answer was helpful. Thanks.